# Set contents of a textbox on a website on a webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am making an app that displays a website using a webview.

I have also setup an intent-filter to receive text content. When that content is received, I want to put it in a textbox that will be on the webpage displayed in the webview.

Is this possible, and if so how do I go about doing it?

Comment: Doesn't sound like an impossible task but it will be easier to help you if you share some code you've written and nail down your problem :)

Comment: Please rephrase the last sentence (the about what you want to do).

Comment: @yoshi I have no idea where to start ;) Currently I only store the text in a string and display the page. I want to put the string into the third textbox on the page...

Comment: So can you show us how you display the page and set up the textboxes? :)

Comment: @yoshi I think you have misunderstood the question... The text boxes are already on a website on the internet, and I want to put text in one of them... I think I may need to send javascript to do it?